# SSRS Expression Divide by Zero Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression

I have a tablix box that has a division expression. When dividing by zero or nulls I get `#Error` displayed in my report. I tried to create an `IIF` statement and tested with static values. This verified my syntax was correct but I still see the error on my reports.

[image: Report Preview]

`=IIF(Sum(Fields!CY_Dollars.Value)=0, 0, (Sum(Fields!CY_Dollars.Value) - Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value))/(Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)))`

So I'm taking Current year dollars, subtracting Previous year dollars, and dividing that total by previous year dollars to get the percentage change. Is there a trick to this that I'm not getting?!

Comment: You mentioned that there are nulls in your data?  Try nesting each field call in a NULL replacement function.  For example, I would the format IIF(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value = Nothing, 0, Fields!PY_Dollars.Value = Nothing) for each Fields!PY_Dollars.Value in the current formula.
Better yet, handle the nulls in the source query instead.

Comment: The condition in your `IIF` statement is not checking for zero denominator (you are checking for zero in *CY*, not *PY* value). Instead, try: `=IIF(Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)=0, 0, (Sum(Fields!CY_Dollars.Value) - Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value))/(Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value))) `

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can add a function to your report code that handles the divide by zero condition, this makes it a bit easier to implement in multiple cells, e.g.

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
  Return 0
Else
  Return Dividend/Divisor
End If
End Function
```

You can then call this in a cell like so:

```
=Code.Divider(Fields!FieldA.Value, Fields!FieldB.Value)
```

Comment: can we use Code.Divider() custom function in SQL or MDX within dataset ? Silly but I want something like this to avoid multiline IIF expressions in my huge MDX :(

Comment: Mi Hero!! This worked out excellent! I didn't really know how to add a function to a report before... so I went but it is sooo easy!

1. In Design view, right-click the design surface outside the border of the report and click Report Properties.
2. Click Code.
3. In Custom code, type the code

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx

Comment: Why no Float type in ssrs?  Getting "There is an error on line n of custom code: [BC30002] Type 'Float' is not defined."

Comment: @GaryThomann handling the dividend isn't necessary as zero or null divided by anything just returns zero, not an error.

Comment: Greetings from the future! It's 2021 and publishing SSRS reports to PowerBI via the API throws an error when you have shared code. I am right now unwinding a bunch of `DivideBy` calls to get this to work.

Comment: Hi Nick, is that by design or due to a bug in the API?

Comment: It seems like a bug because these reports can be published manually from the SSRS editor and run fine inside Power BI.

Comment: So... if anyone has to refactor their shared divide code out, this is an inline method that actually works https://sqldusty.com/2011/08/01/ssrs-expression-iif-statement-divide-by-zero-error/ . Basically `IIF(denominator=0,0,Numerator) / IIF(Denominator=0,1,Denominator)`

Answer (score 15):

I suspect you're running into the issue where SSRS doesn't actually short circuit an `IIF` statement; even though you're checking for *0*, you're still going to hit a divide by zero error.

Try something like:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value) = 0, 0, Sum(Fields!CY_Dollars.Value) - Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value))
  / IIf(Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value))
```

Using two `IIf` statements means you avoid the error by using the equation `0/1` when `Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)` = 0, thus just returning *0*.

Also note that the above expression is checking `Sum(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value) = 0`, but yours is checking `Sum(Fields!CY_Dollars.Value) = 0` - the denominator needs the zero check here.

Comment: I understand the logic and it should work but SSRS doens't calculate it correctly. I still get the error with this.

Comment: +1. Here is a post on using double iif statements http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2010/03/12/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-iif-statement-divide-by-zero-error/

Answer (score 10):

To avoid the overhead of maintaining code, the solution below feels tidiest to me. It avoids the division by zero in the denominator by adding the smallest possible `Double` value to it (`Double.Epsilon`, which is `4.94e-324`). This value's way too small to affect the value of the fraction for anything people would use SSRS for. It also avoids nesting IIF functions.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Denominator.Value)>0, 
     Sum(Fields!Numerator.Value)/(Sum(Fields!Denominator.Value)+Double.Epsilon),
     nothing)
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. In fact, by adding the Double.Epsilon to the denominator, you don't even need the iif statement anymore.

Comment: This has really saved my Friday. Thank you so much for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just express the values as DOUBLE? This avoids the multiple IIF functions? It should have better performance too.

```
=IIF(Sum(CDbl(Fields!CY_Dollars.Value))=0, 0, (Sum(CDbl(Fields!CY_Dollars.Value)) - 
    Sum(CDbl(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value)))/(Sum(CDbl(Fields!PY_Dollars.Value))))
```