# RDLC expression error

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Hopefully I might have the easiest question to answer but so far I couldn't figure it out. I have a RDLC report with following expression.

```
    =Iif(Sum(Fields!OriginalTotal.Value) = 0, 0, (Sum(Fields!WorkingTotal.Value) - Sum(Fields!OriginalTotal.Value))/Sum(Fields!OriginalTotal.Value))
```

Please note that this field on the report is formatted as percentage with two decimal places.

Problem is whenever the Sum(Fields!OriginalTotal.Value) = 0 condition is true, field prints as "#Error" on the report.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a well known problem that ssrs calculates both expressions of "iif". That's why you get Error when trying to divide on 0.

Have a look at the following links:

- http://www.reportingservicestips.co.uk/RSTip008.html
- [SSRS Expression Divide by Zero Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189132/ssrs-expression-divide-by-zero-error)

Comment: help me in mi problem `=Fields!Saldo.Value*100/Fields!CostoNeto.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Writing expression in SSRS. We can add a function to your report code that handles the divide by zero condition, this makes it a bit easier to implement in multiple cells(code re-usability),

Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
  Return 0
Else
  Return Dividend/Divisor
End If
End Function

We can call this code in a cell as follows,

=Code.Divider(Fields!Dividend.Value, Fields!Divisor.Value)

Thanks
Venky