# REPLACE Nan in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, nan

I have the following issue in SSRS when I'm doing the following calculations.

For the columns under Total Number - I'm doing the following -

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CallbackStatus.Value="Completed",1,0))
```

and

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CallbackStatus.Value="Outstanding",1,0))
```

In this particular example  - the Total number of Callbacks is 0.
Why by using the above expression would the below not pull back a 0 and instead a blank field.

Also in the % of Total I'm getting NaN. I'm also wanting that to be 0 if it's NaN.
The functions for this is below -

```
=ReportItems!Textbox57.Value / ReportItems!Textbox54.Value
```

and

```
=ReportItems!Textbox61.Value / ReportItems!Textbox54.Value
```

any help would be great. Thanks

[image: report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first issue, I'd change the expression from a Sum to a Count (since it sounds like you're truly counting the matching records):

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!CallbackStatus.Value="Completed",1,Nothing))
```

Regarding the NaN problem, it's returning NaN ("Not a Number"), because the expression is trying to divide by 0. I'd use an IIf expression such as:

```
=IIf(ReportItems!Textbox54.Value=0, Nothing, ReportItems!Textbox61.Value / ReportItems!Textbox54.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Nan divide by zero error, you can add some report code to handle this issue, see my answer here:

[SSRS Expression Divide by Zero Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189132/ssrs-expression-divide-by-zero-error/19216804#19216804)