# SSRS cell Expression produces #ERROR in cell when report is run

Tags: ssrs-2008

Anyone know why the following expression would make my cell just say "#ERROR"?

=IIf(Sum(Fields!curr.Value) = 0, 0, Sum(Fields!due.Value) / Sum(Fields!curr.Value))

Is it not short circuiting so it still hits the division by zero?  If so, would there be a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft thinks they are smarter than you and are checking for a divide by zero even though you'll never hit it because of your logic.

The **Trick** (i.e. Workaround for Microsoft's propensity for "helping" and making things worse) is to use another IIF:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!curr.Value) = 0, 0, Sum(Fields!due.Value)) / IIF(Sum(Fields!curr.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!curr.Value))
```

[SSRS Expression Divide by Zero Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189132/ssrs-expression-divide-by-zero-error)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ef1a0375-414e-41f4-b32f-3b782c5b4c85/error-using-iif-and-divide-by-zero?forum=sqlreportingservices