# Expression Working on Some Fields but not Others in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I am using the following expression in one of my reports:

```
=Iif(fields!occ.Value=0,0,Sum(Fields!RIemps.Value) / Sum(Fields!occ.Value))
```

The calculation is working for some of the fields but not for others.  When I replace the second "0" with Sum(Fields!occ.Value) then the occupancy works and the calculation runs as it should providing the occupancy value as stated:

```
=Iif(fields!occ.Value=0,Sum(Fields!occ.Value),Sum(Fields!RIemps.Value) / Sum(Fields!occ.Value))
```

When I reverse the query, the fields which were working do not and the the ones that were not, now work:

```
=Iif(fields!occ.Value=0,Sum(Fields!RIemps.Value) / Sum(Fields!occ.Value),0)
```

I cannot get all fields to work consistently, it is either one or the other.  Any thoughts on what might be triggering the inconsistency in the expression?

Comment: This does not look like SQL. What kind of tool or database is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS Expression Divide by Zero Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189132/ssrs-expression-divide-by-zero-error)