# Remove NaN in Nested iif in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, nan, iif

New to SQL-SSRS

How do I add functionality to the below code to change returned NaN values to 0 or blank?  What I think is happening is in situations that the sum of Agreed and Disagreed = 0 I am getting this Nan.  I think this would be easier for me if I wasnt dealing with the Agreed and Disagreed categories.  Again, new to SQL programming.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
=(Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed",Fields!Days.Value,0)) + Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed",Fields!Days.Value,0)))/(Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed",Fields!Fq.Value,0)) + Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed",Fields!Fq.Value,0)))
```

Comment: Simply replace NaN with 0... Or Use Single.IsNAN

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below,

```
=Replace((Sum(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed",Fields!Days.Value,0)) + 
Sum(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed",Fields!Days.Value,0))),"NaN","0")
/ Replace((Sum(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed",Fields!Fq.Value,0)) 
+ Sum(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed",Fields!Fq.Value,0))),"NaN","0")
```

Also, look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189132/ssrs-expression-divide-by-zero-error/19216804#19216804)

Comment: What you have written inside expression?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than replacing the text returned from dividing by zero, you should handle the DIV 0 issue in the expression:

```
=IIF(
    SUM(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed" OR Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed", Fields!Fq.Value, 0)) = 0, 0, 
        SUM(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed" OR Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed", Fields!Days.Value, 0)))
/IIF(
    SUM(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed" OR Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed", Fields!Fq.Value, 0)) = 0, 1, 
        SUM(IIF(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed" OR Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed", Fields!Fq.Value, 0)))
```

If the SUM is **zero**, the calculation is **0 / 1** otherwise it's the **SUM(Days) / SUM(Fq)** where the Response is **Agreed** or **Disagreed**.

And rather than two sum, just use an OR in the one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
  Return 0
Else
  Return Dividend/Divisor
End If
End Function
```

this function enables you to write a custom code which fixes all problems with Nan .
this can be called by below

```
=Code.Divider(Fields!FieldA.Value, Fields!FieldB.Value)
```

your code is as below

```
=Code.Divider(((Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed",Fields!Days.Value,0)) + Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed",Fields!Days.Value,0))), ((Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Agreed",Fields!Fq.Value,0)) + Sum(iif(Fields!Response.Value = "Disagreed",Fields!Fq.Value,0)))))
```